# Connect to docker postgres from golang application

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

I am trying to connect to docker postgres database from the golang code. Command used to create the postgres container: `docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --name my-postgres -p 5432:5432 postgres` To create the database I run:

```
PS C:\Users\Aylin\Desktop\farmers> docker exec -it my-postgres bash
root@8969058907f8:/# psql -U postgres
psql (13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE test_db;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \q
```

I can connect to this database from pgadmin docker container: `docker run --rm -p 5050:5050 thajeztah/pgadmin4` using the IP address returned by `docker inspect my-postgres` command as Host name/address for a new server in pgAdmin 4

```
"Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2", -> host address
```

However, when I try to connect to the database from the application using the same parameters I'm getting the following error:

```
[2021-04-20 17:04:43]  sql: database is closed 
dial tcp 172.17.0.2:5432: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Go code:

```
const (
    host     = "172.17.0.2"
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "password"
    dbname   = "test_db"
    port     = 5432
)

func FetchConnection() *gorm.DB {

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)

    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
}
```

How can I make this code work? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once you've launched a container with a `docker run -p` option, to non-container processes, it looks exactly like any other server process that's listening on that port.

If:

- The host process and Docker container are running on the same host (or in the same VM);
- You've started the container with a correct `-p HOST:CONTAINER` port mapping; and
- You're not running Docker Toolbox or otherwise have Docker in a VM

Then the host process can access the container process using `localhost` as a host name and the first `-p` port number.

Never use `docker inspect` or other means to look up the container-private IP address.  It's unreachable in most common setups (it only works if you're on the same native-Linux host; not from other hosts, VMs, or on MacOS or Windows) and is never necessary.  Similarly, you shouldn't normally need to use `docker exec` or other debugging tools to access your database, since you can use normal clients like `psql` talking to the published port.

Comment: I changed host to "localhost", but it says pq: database "mytestdb" does not exist, although it's listed in psql                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges     
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------  
 mytestdb  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |

Comment: It's probably because there is no mytestdb database on my local Postgres server. How do I point to the docker postgres container instead?